# How to add different chart design to a visual studio project?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2015, charts

Hi everyone I have a question, I need to use a different(styled) looking chart types (ex : pie, column charts) for my visual studio project. The project's code language is c# and I have an html script. My question is : how and where can I find and include new chart to my project ? The following function defines the chart type etc :

```
  protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart1.Visible = ddlCountries.SelectedValue != "";
        string query = string.Format("select shipcity, count(orderid) from orders where shipcountry = '{0}' group by shipcity", ddlCountries.SelectedValue);
        DataTable dt = GetData(query);
        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
    }
```

I put this function code because it may help you to understand me :)
Have a good day

Comment: do you want the different styles in the same chart? or do you have multiple chart objects?

Comment: @MongZhu I need different styles in the same chart if it's possible :)

Comment: @MongZhu thank you for your post :) But I didn't understand how does it change the visual of a chart? I mean I need more appealing chart :)

Comment: it changes a line chart to a bar chart and so on. What do you mean by "more appealing chart"?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the `ChartType` according to your needs. If you want the same data to be displayed in a different style, you don't even need to bind new data points to the `Series`.

Here is a small program to demostrate this. It has a list of `SeriesChartTypes` which are bound to a `ComboBox` where you can choose the styles:

```
List<SeriesChartType> typeList = new List<SeriesChartType>() {
                                     SeriesChartType.Pie, 
                                     SeriesChartType.Line, 
                                     SeriesChartType.Bar };

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = typeList;
}
```

Furthermore it has a normal `Chart` object. In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the combobox it simply assigns test data and the chosen `SeriesChartType` to the `Series` and the chart redraws itself.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        SeriesChartType type = typeList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];

        List<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1 };

        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(values);

        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = type;
    }
}
```